# For loop with InsertOnSubmit() - SubmitChanges() inside or outside the loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Editing someone else code, and am wondering whether when using a for loop and InsertOnSubmit, does the submitchanges call go inside or outside the loop.

I.E:

```
foreach (string t in newTags)
{
   Tag q_tag = new Q_Tag();
   q_tag.Q_ID = updated.Q_ID;
   q_tag.Tag_Name = t;
   TheData.Q_Tags.InsertOnSubmit(q_tag);
   TheData.SubmitChanges();         
}
```

As opposed to:

```
foreach (string t in newTags)
{
   Tag q_tag = new Q_Tag();
   q_tag.Q_ID = updated.Q_ID;
   q_tag.Tag_Name = t;
   TheData.Q_Tags.InsertOnSubmit(q_tag);     
}

TheData.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: It also depends on whether or not you want to isolate the change. Inside it will fail on each insertion, but with a try catch you can keep going, outside the loop you're saving your changes in a batch all or nothing mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new connection is opened to the database and is closed at the end of the function call in the first one. In the second code, a single connection is opened and closed after all operations. Second one is way much faster than the first one. You can try it yourself later, but my tests shown nearly %30 speed rate change.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either way. Read this short article from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx You should probably do it outside of the loop so you only do it once. That should give the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say outside of the loop. From the [DataContext.SubmitChanges MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx):

> Computes **the set** of modified objects to be inserted, updated, or
>   deleted, and executes the appropriate commands to implement the
>   changes to the database.

So with that in mind, it would be more efficient to do it outside of the loop, as the method will insert all of the objects with one invocation.